# How to set the initial zoom settings in leaflet/mapbox as a fractional value?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I was using this

> L.mapbox.map('map-canvas', 'mapbox.streets',{legendControl:{postion: 'bottomright'}}).setView([1.35, 103.8], 11);

You can see the last 11 as the zoom factor, 11 is a bit bigger for my div and when I try 10 it becomes a bit too smaller. I used 10.x but then the behaviour of the map is changing and only a part of the map in the center is being shown.
Please answer if you know some other way to set initial zoom settings which could help me.Thanks

Comment: Float problem still a problem :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe current `L.mapbox` version is based on Leaflet version 0.7, which does **not** support fractional zoom level.

Leaflet version 1.0.0 (still at release candidate state) will provide such support. Mapbox will surely update its version once it is released.